# Typing an 11 x 11 (or larger) Matrix

Tags: matrices

I would like to explicitly write out a n x n matrices in my paper, but once `n \geq 11`, I get compiling errors and it refuses to print the matrix.  Here is what I have:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amsthm}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

$$\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
-\fract{1}{2} & -\fract{1}{2} & \fract{1}{2}\sqrt{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0  & -\fract{1}{2}\sqrt{2} & \fract{1}{2}\sqrt{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0  & 0  & -\fract{1}{2}\sqrt{2} & \fract{1}{2}\sqrt{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0  & 0  & 0 & -\fract{1}{2}\sqrt{2} & \fract{1}{2}\sqrt{2}& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0  & 0  & 0 & 0 & -\fract{1}{2}\sqrt{2} & \fract{1}{2}\sqrt{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0  & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\fract{1}{2}\sqrt{2} & \fract{1}{2}\sqrt{2} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0  & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\fract{1}{2}\sqrt{2} & \fract{1}{2}\sqrt{2}  & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\fract{1}{2}\sqrt{2} & \fract{1}{2} & \fract{-1}{2}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix*} $$

\end{document}
```

I do not see any errors for this 11 x 11 matrix.  However, when I type this in a blank standalone document, I get an error that says:  "Missing $ inserted.    $$\begin{bmatrix*}[r]"

Is there another way to write an 11 x 11 (or larger) matrix so that it compiles?  Or is it impossible to type matrices this large into LaTeX?  (If it helps, I am using writelatex.com to compile my thesis.)

Comment: You need to reset the counter variable `MaxMatrixCols`. Its default value is `10`. If you need, say, 15 cols, issue the instruction `\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{15}`. (See also footnote 2 on page 10 of the user guide of the amsmath package.)

Comment: Some additional observations. There is no `\fract` command; I assume you meant to write `\frac`. Similarly, there's no `bmatrix*` environment; try `bmatrix` instead. The use of `$$` to enter and exit displaymath mode in a LaTeX document is deprecated; see [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) for more information on this subject. Finally, you're getting the error message about the missing `$` because you're trying to use the `standalone` document class without setting the option `preview`.

Comment: Thank you!!  I didn't know there's a max amount of columns allowed for matrices.  This is incredibly helpful!  Yes, I did mean `\frac`, and not `\fract`.  I'm glad you pointed it out.

`bmatrix*` allows me to align right `[r]` or left `[l]`.  If I use `bmatrix`, then some how it does not understand that I want a specific alignment.  It will think `[r]` is in the first row first column and it will do a default center alignment.

Comment: As for the `preview` option you mentioned:  for future reference, how might I add that?

Comment: `\documentclass[preview]{standalone}`. About the `bmatrix*` environment: You're absulutely correct, it does exist (as it's defined in the the `mathtools` package).

Comment: Thank you again!  I appreciate your detailed answers.  I do not always know which package I am using, but I know I can do certain things.  So I appreciate you mentioning which package allows me to use that command. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Summarizing some of my earlier comments:

- Use the `standalone` package with the option `preview` in order to avoid getting an error message about a missing `$` symbol.
- Don't use `$$` in a LaTeX document to start and end displaymath mode, as it's quite deprecated. [See Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) for more information on this subject.
- The matrix environments of the `amsmath` and `mathtools` environments work with the counter variable `MaxMatrixCols`. Its default value is `10`; if you have a matrix with, say, 15 columns, issue the instruction `\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{15}`.
- There is no `\fract` command; use `\frac` instead.

For the matrix at hand, I actually wouldn't use any `\frac` instructions. Instead, I'd use inline-style math notation, i.e., I'd write `\sqrt{2}/2`, etc. That way, the fractional expressions won't become too tiny to read with ease.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{geometry,mathtools}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{11}
\begin{document}
\[ 
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
-1/2 & -1/2 & \sqrt{2}/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0  & -\sqrt{2}/2 & \sqrt{2}/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0  & 0  & -\sqrt{2}/2 & \sqrt{2}/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0  & 0  & 0 & -\sqrt{2}/2 & \sqrt{2}/2& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0  & 0  & 0 & 0 & -\sqrt{2}/2 & \sqrt{2}/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0  & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\sqrt{2}/2 & \sqrt{2}/2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0  & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\sqrt{2}/2 & \sqrt{2}/2  & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\sqrt{2}/2 & 1/2 & -1/2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix*} 
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: maybe use `sfrac{}{}` of the xfrac package for the fractions ;) looks quite nice.