# Error with large matrix

Tags: matrices

I am trying to produce a very large matrix:

```
\[
CM = \begin{bmatrix}
              0&          0&          0&     1.0000&          0&     1.0000&          0&     2.0000&          0&     3.3809&          0&     3.3809&          0&     2.3810&          0&    20.1921&          0&    20.1921\\
              0&          0&          0&          0&     1.0000&          0&    -2.0000&          0&    -2.0000&          0&    -6.1904&          0&    -2.3810&          0&    -2.3810&          0&     8.7975&          0\\
              0&          0&          0&          0&          0&     1.0000&          0&          0&          0&          0&          0&    -3.1904&          0&          0&          0&          0&          0&    10.1787\\
         1.0000&          0&     1.0000&          0&     2.0000&          0&     3.3809&          0&     3.3809&          0&     2.3810&          0&    20.1921&          0&    20.1921&          0&    35.1688&          0\\
              0&     1.0000&          0&    -2.0000&          0&    -2.0000&          0&    -6.1904&          0&    -2.3810&          0&    -2.3810&          0&     8.7975&          0&   -35.1688&          0&   -35.1688\\
              0&          0&     1.0000&          0&          0&          0&          0&          0&    -3.1904&          0&          0&          0&          0&          0&    10.1787&          0&          0&          0
\end{bmatrix}
\]
```

The syntax appears correct to me, but I am getting this error:

> Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. ... 0& 2.0000& 0& 3.3809&

...for each line of my matrix. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    \documentclass[landscape]{article}
    \usepackage[margin=.25in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \begin{document}
    \tiny
    \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{18}
    \[
    CM = \begin{bmatrix}
    0& 0& 0& 1.0000& 0& 1.0000& 0& 2.0000& 0& 3.3809& 0& 3.3809& 0& 2.3810& 0&    20.1921& 0& 20.1921\\
    0& 0& 0& 0& 1.0000& 0& -2.0000& 0& -2.0000& 0& -6.1904& 0& -2.3810& 0& -2.3810&  0& 8.7975& 0\\
    0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1.0000& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& -3.1904& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 10.1787\\
    1.0000& 0& 1.0000& 0& 2.0000& 0& 3.3809& 0& 3.3809& 0& 2.3810& 0& 20.1921& 0& 20.1921& 0& 35.1688& 0\\
    0& 1.0000& 0& -2.0000& 0& -2.0000& 0& -6.1904& 0& -2.3810& 0& -2.3810& 0& 8.7975& 0& -35.1688& 0& -35.1688\\
    0& 0& 1.0000& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& -3.1904& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 10.1787& 0& 0& 0
    \end{bmatrix}
    \]

    \end{document}
```

Ref: [Typing an 11 x 11 (or larger) Matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212816/typing-an-11-x-11-or-larger-matrix) and of course the amsldoc.pdf manual.